# Data Not stored in Sequence (oder) by row in AWS Dynamo DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am writing data to AWS Dynamo DB by describing "hash key" only (I am not using the sort key). I am getting problem that in Dynamo Db data is not stored in row sequence. Code and picture is attached for review.

```
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
import boto3
import json
import decimal
import datetime
import time

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

# Helper class to convert a DynamoDB item to JSON.
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            if o % 1 > 0:
                return float(o)
            else:
                return int(o)
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)

table = dynamodb.create_table(
    TableName='Alarms',
    KeySchema=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'Date',
            'KeyType': 'HASH'  #Partition key
        }
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'Date',
            'AttributeType': 'S'
        },

    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput={
        'ReadCapacityUnits': 5,
        'WriteCapacityUnits': 5
    }
)

print("Table status:", table.table_status)

# Wait until the table exists.
table.meta.client.get_waiter('table_exists').wait(TableName='Alarms')

table = dynamodb.Table('Alarms')


with open("alarm.json") as json_file:
    alarms = json.load(json_file, parse_float = decimal.Decimal)
    for alarm in alarms:
        FNB = alarm['FNB']
        FRE = alarm['FRE']
        MB = alarm['MB']
        TB = alarm['TB']
        TD1 = alarm['TD1']
        TD2 = alarm['TD2']
        TW = alarm['TW']

        Date = str(datetime.datetime.now())

        table.put_item(
           Item={
               'Date': Date,
               'FNB': FNB,
               'FRE': FRE,
               'MB': MB,
               'TB': TB,
               'TD1': TD1,
               'TD2': TD2,
               'TW': TW,
            }
        )

        newstr = json.dumps(alarm, cls=DecimalEncoder).replace('\"','').strip('{}')
        print('Date:', Date,',', newstr) 
        time.sleep(1)
```

Expected Output (Wanted Output) in Dynamo DB:

```
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:20.309674 , FRE: 0, MB: 0, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:21.695486 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:22.870489 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 1
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:23.983862 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 1, TB: 1
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:25.101755 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 1, TD1: 1, TB: 1
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:26.213475 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 1, TD2: 1, TD1: 1, TB: 1
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:27.324465 , FRE: 0, MB: 0, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:28.435475 , FRE: 0, MB: 0, TW: 0, FNB: 1, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:29.546471 , FRE: 0, MB: 0, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:30.658182 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:31.768494 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 1
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:32.886541 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 1, TB: 1
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:34.046496 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 1, TD1: 1, TB: 1
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:35.222471 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 1, TD2: 1, TD1: 1, TB: 1
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:36.339477 , FRE: 0, MB: 0, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:37.450506 , FRE: 0, MB: 0, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 1, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:38.563476 , FRE: 0, MB: 0, TW: 0, FNB: 1, TD2: 1, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:39.675500 , FRE: 0, MB: 0, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:40.789492 , FRE: 0, MB: 0, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:41.900886 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:43.014493 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 1
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:44.125980 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 1, TB: 1
```

Output Come (Stored in Dynamo Db)

```
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:26.213475 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 1, TD2: 1, TD1: 1, TB: 1
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:27.324465 , FRE: 0, MB: 0, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:28.435475 , FRE: 0, MB: 0, TW: 0, FNB: 1, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:29.546471 , FRE: 0, MB: 0, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:20.309674 , FRE: 0, MB: 0, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:21.695486 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:22.870489 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 1
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:23.983862 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 1, TB: 1
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:25.101755 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 1, TD1: 1, TB: 1
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:36.339477 , FRE: 0, MB: 0, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:37.450506 , FRE: 0, MB: 0, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 1, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:38.563476 , FRE: 0, MB: 0, TW: 0, FNB: 1, TD2: 1, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:39.675500 , FRE: 0, MB: 0, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:40.789492 , FRE: 0, MB: 0, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:41.900886 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:43.014493 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 1
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:44.125980 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 1, TB: 1
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:29.546471 , FRE: 0, MB: 0, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:30.658182 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 0
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:31.768494 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 1
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:32.886541 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 1, TB: 1
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:34.046496 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 1, TD1: 1, TB: 1
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:35.222471 , FRE: 0, MB: 1, TW: 0, FNB: 1, TD2: 1, TD1: 1, TB: 1
Date: 2016-11-09 08:57:36.339477 , FRE: 0, MB: 0, TW: 0, FNB: 0, TD2: 0, TD1: 0, TB: 0
```

So it is not stored in sequence in Dynamo Db. How this problem is resolved.

Comment: Do you mean DynamoDB is not maintaining the insertion order?

Comment: @notionquest yes that i mean. insertion order is not maintain.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have partition-key, DynamoDB doesn't guarantee that data is sorted on it.

If you have both partition-key and sort-key, then DynamoDB guarantees that data for a given partition-key will be sorted on sort-key.